# Next Framework won't even return me a console.log

Tags: next.js

Just as the title said, i cannot fetch data from a json neither display a console log from _app.js in NextJS.

My code:

```
//pages/_app.js
import '../css/font-awesome.min.css'
import '../css/owl.carousel.css'
import '../css/owl.transitions.css'
import '../css/animate.min.css'
import '../css/lightbox.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../css/preloader.css'
import '../css/image.css'
import '../css/icon.css'
import '../css/style.css'
import '../css/responsive.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css'


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, json }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} json={json}/>
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("test")
  const res = await api.get("./api/test.json");
  console.log(res)
  const json = res.data;
  console.log(json);
  return {
    props: {
      json,
    },
  };
}

export default MyApp
```

I doesn't return anything in console... I need to link the frontend and the backend but i cannot make it to work. Tried with getStaticProps, getInitialProps, etc... But it doesn't return anything on console. Even when the function is called it gives me undefined with a local json.

Another approach

```
//pages/api/bienvenido.js
const Bienvenido = ({ bienvenidos, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      {bienvenidos.map(bienvenido => (
        <li key={bienvenido.id}>{bienvenido.id}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
Bienvenido.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  try {
    // Parses the JSON returned by a network request
    const parseJSON = resp => (resp.json ? resp.json() : resp);
    // Checks if a network request came back fine, and throws an error if not
    const checkStatus = resp => {
      if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
        return resp;
      }

      return parseJSON(resp).then(resp => {
        throw resp;
      });
    };

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    const bienvenidos = await fetch('test.json', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
    })
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON);

    return { bienvenidos };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

export default Bienvenido;
```

This returns Undefined on this line "const Bienvenido = ({ bienvenidos, error }) => {"

Comment: Are you looking at the browser console or the build console? getStaticProps is going to run at build time and build time ONLY. You should see it there; it is not in the browser console. getServerSideProps will also run on the server, but it will run on each page generation.

Comment: Browser console...

Comment: I'd suggest using getServerSideProps and looking at the nodejs console -- you should see console.log outputs from that function in there. NextJS will sever render your page on every visit and run the getServerSideProps on the server then pass the outputs to the page react component. getStaticProps does similar, but at build time (so just once).

Comment: I'm using vsc terminal but it doesnt show anything either, i will try to reinstall the node inspect module.

Comment: Two things worth noting: `getStaticProps` doesn't work in [`_app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), you have to use `getInitialProps` there; also, files under `pages/api` folder are for [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction), you shouldn't have frontend/React code in there.

Comment: @juliomalves is right. You can find that in _app you can only use getInitialProps. Take a look at the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)